# Phaser timer controlled text trouble

Tags: events, timer, phaser-framework, phaserjs

I'm trying to have some text that shows one line at a time then change scenes, using events. I'm having trouble though. Here is the code I'm using:

```js
this.query.setText('What was his job?');
var unemployed = this.add.sprite(600, 600, 'unemployedButton').setInteractive();
var cop = this.add.sprite(1080, 600, 'copButton').setInteractive();

unemployed.on('pointerdown', function (pointer) {

    this.query.setText('Thats a lie. He did have a job.');
    this.time.addEvent({
        delay: 2500,
        callback: () => this.query.setText('He was a police officer. He never was a security guard.'),
        callbackScope: this,
    });
    this.time.addEvent({
        delay: 5000,
        callback: () => this.query.setText('He never lost his job or struggled with money.'),
        callbackScope: this,
    });
    this.time.addEvent({
        delay: 7500,
        callback: () => this.query.setText('He had gone to visit a fellow officer that day.'),
        callbackScope: this,
    });
    this.time.addEvent({
        delay: 10000,
        callback: () => this.query.setText('He was shocked to find the window smashed and his friend dead.'),
        callbackScope: this,
    });
    this.time.addEvent({
        delay: 12500,
        callback: () => jobQuestion = false,
        callbackScope: this,
    });
    this.time.addEvent({
        delay: 12501,
        callback: () => this.scene.start('menu'),
        callbackScope: this,
    });

}, this);

cop.on('pointerdown', function (pointer) {

    this.query.setText('Yes, hes was a police officer.');
    this.time.addEvent({
        delay: 2500,
        callback: () => this.query.setText('He never lost his job, nor was he ever security guard.'),
        callbackScope: this,
    });
    this.time.addEvent({
        delay: 5000,
        callback: () => this.query.setText('That part was a lie to make him look like a criminal.'),
        callbackScope: this,
    });
    this.time.addEvent({
        delay: 7500,
        callback: () => this.query.setText('He had gone to visit a fellow officer that day.'),
        callbackScope: this,
    });
    this.time.addEvent({
        delay: 10000,
        callback: () => this.query.setText('He was shocked to find the window smashed and his friend dead.'),
        callbackScope: this,
    });
    this.time.addEvent({
        delay: 12500,
        callback: () => jobQuestion = false,
        callbackScope: this,
    });
    this.time.addEvent({
        delay: 12501,
        callback: () => this.scene.start('menu'),
        callbackScope: this,
    });
}, this);
```

The code is supposed to show one of two series of lines based on a button that the player clicked on. But as it is now, when the player clicks a button, it just shows, the first the initial question (the first thing this.query is set to) for a while and then goes to the menu scene.

I'm not sure what I did wrong. I swear it was working earlier, before I added the parts with the boolean and the scene change. Can someone tell me where I messed up and how do I fix it?

If it helps, I'm using Phaser 3 in VSCode.

Comment: No error appears to be visible when I click inspect. I got no clue where the error is coming from.

Comment: Do you think something is overriding the text changes?

Comment: I'm certain I only clicked once.

Comment: Any chance that this is happening because my code is in the update method, and I have to move it to the create method?

Comment: I admit that I create this.query in the create method, and that everything else its involved with is in the update method.

Comment: This code should NOT be in the `update` function. The `update` function is call 60 times per minute. That means you are attaching 60 eventlisteners for the clicks, per minute. **This is the cause of the error.** _In my code I alway created the click events in the `create` function._

Comment: ok. Moving it all to the create method worked. Thanks. Just one last thing I'm curious about, in what units is the delay in? Milliseconds? Just, how much is a second when setting the delay when adding events?

Comment: Yes, the delay units are milliseconds( [link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Types.Time.html#.TimerEventConfig)). 1sec = 1000ms. I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Update:**
> If the code is really in the `update` functio, this is the cause of the error, since eventlisteners will be call on each `update` function is call (~ 60 times per minute). Move this to the `create` function, as in my demo code, and the problem should be fixed.

The problem must be somewhere else, or you are clicking multiple times, because the code should work.

**Here a demo:**

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var boolVariable = false

class FirstScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super('FirstScene')
    }

    create() {
        this.label1 = this.add.text(50, 80, '')
            .setScale(2)
            .setOrigin(0)
            .setStyle({ fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial' });

        let button = this.add.rectangle(10, 10, 200, 50, 0xffffff)
            .setOrigin(0)
            .setInteractive();

        let buttonText = this.add.text(0, 0, 'Press me')
            .setScale(1.5)
            .setColor('#000000')
            .setOrigin(0.5)
            .setStyle({ fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial' });

        Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(buttonText, button);

        button.on('pointerdown', function (pointer) {
            console.info(1)
            this.label1.setText('Initial Text');
            this.time.addEvent({
                delay: 1000,
                callback: () => this.label1.setText(`Text 1 boolVariable: ${boolVariable}`),
                callbackScope: this,
            });

            this.time.addEvent({
                delay: 2000,
                callback: () => this.label1.setText(`Text 2 boolVariable: ${boolVariable}`),
                callbackScope: this,
            });

            this.time.addEvent({
                delay: 2500,
                callback: () => boolVariable = true,
                callbackScope: this,
            });

            this.time.addEvent({
                delay: 3000,
                callback: () => this.label1.setText(`Text 3 boolVariable: ${boolVariable}`),
                callbackScope: this,
            });


            this.time.addEvent({
                delay: 4000,
                callback: () => this.scene.start('menu'),
                callbackScope: this,
            });

        }, this);
    }
}


class SecondScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super('menu')
    }

    create() {
        this.label1 = this.add.text(50, 50, 'MENU SCENE')
            .setScale(2.5)
            .setOrigin(0)
            .setStyle({ fontStyle: 'bold', fontFamily: 'Arial' });
    }
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: [FirstScene, SecondScene]
};

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```